# The soft keyboard that pops up from the input box will squeeze the Flutter page

Tags: java, android, flutter

Compile the Flutter project into aar and then reference it into an Android native project written in Java. After jumping to this Flutter page, a keyboard that pops up with an input box will appear to push the page up, with a blank area in the middle. A Flutter project that runs directly will not encounter this situation. What is the reason for this?

Flutter code is the same, what would affect it? The FlutterActivity in the Android project also uses Android: windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", but it has no effect.

Comment: Please provide your complete minimal reproduction flutter code.